# Add || and && to ternanry render in React className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render a component with class name taht is depending on my two differrent `useState` cases.

```
<div className="Player" onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)} onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}>
 <div className={`playerNavigation__container ${!pause ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}`}>
    <Buttons to={'/'} className={'back'}>
       <img className="btn__back-img" src={back} alt="btn__back" />
     </Buttons>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my class I was trying to use `${!pause || !hover? 'hidden' : 'visible'}` but this was not working

I am wondering how i can properly render this.

Comment: *but this was not working* - in what way? Please give more details as to what you expected vs what you observed.

Comment: Are you sure that `pause` is a boolean?

Comment: Personally I'd probably end the string and have a ternary like `className={'playerNavigation__container ' + (!pause || !hover ? 'hidden' : 'visible')}`

Comment: Thanks mate this worked in general. Stil one edge case that is not working but 90% is good :)